# mongoDB in .net environment cannot connect

Tags: c#, vb.net, mongodb

I downloaded the necessary c# library and tried to do a basic connect but it does not seem to recognize the C# library and fails with trying to access the files with No Source Available message.

```
Locating source for 'C:\build\mongo-csharp-driver\Driver
\Core\MongoClient.cs'. Checksum: MD5 {7f d4 a9 70 6d 1 24 e 31 bb 0 2e 91 6 8c 9e}
The file 'C:\build\mongo-csharp-driver\Driver\Core\MongoClient.cs' 
does not exist.
```

I used the Nuget Package to install and it seems to be looking an incorrect source folder. Here is my code though...

```
    Dim connectionString As String = "mongodb://127.0.0.1"
    Dim client = New MongoClient(connectionString)
    Dim server As MongoServer
    Dim db As MongoDatabase
    Dim siteCollection As MongoCollection

    server = client.GetServer()

    db = server.GetDatabase("test")
    siteCollection = db("test")
```

Comment: What's probably happening is that `MongoClient` is throwing an exception and Visual Studio is looking for the source code for the source of the exception.  But that doesn't really matter, look at the details of the exception for a description of the problem.

Comment: Is MongoDB running? (That's a common cause)

Comment: thanks. I changed the connection string to localhost. Still have not got this to work and started a new version in Java to coordinate with other processes running.